# Lock all domain shared folder to an admin domain user

Tags: windows-server-2008, administrator, active-directory, windows-domain

Is it possible to lock all the shared folder of the domain to an administrator user? This user must be an administrator because it has to install application on the server, but must not see the files.

Unfortunately it is impossible to create a local administrator user, but I can create an Admin User, let him remotely log-in only on one DC and then let him manage this server, but I'm not able to lock the shared folder of the other domain computers.

Comment: You can indeed share folder with a specific user or custom group.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. If you are asking can you share a folder where a Domain Admin has read access but cannot write to it, sure, no problem.

Comment: I'd like to lock all permission to all shared folder to a Domain Admin user